# Paperclip, where are the actual files stored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

This is how I configured my attachment:

```
has_attached_file :image, {styles: { small: "64x64", med: "100x100", large: "200x200" },
                  :url  => "/assets/images/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/images/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :default_url => "users/default/:style/missing.png"}
```

The output seems to be correct:

`<img alt="Missing" src="/assets/images/users/3/small/missing.png?1426087812">`

However, when I navigate to the path in my windows explorer I cannot see any files.

I am running in development mode. Is that the cause? How can I find the actual files?

Comment: Does your app have permissions to write to that directory?

Comment: I don't remember specifying that anywhere particularly. As long as the uploaded picture can be displayed it must be stored somewhere. If I navigate to this path in explorer: src="/assets/images/users/3/small/missing.png?1426087812" I cannot find anything.

Comment: and the file doesn't show in your local file system? also, can you post your paperclip initializer?

Comment: I must be retarded in some sense. I just cannot see them in my file explorer. No new folder are created..nothing..

Comment: The file is successfully uploaded and displayed in my browser. If I change it with a new image a new path is generated and so and a new image is displayed. My user record is updated with the new image properties. It just doesn't show up in file explorer. It must be something about development environment settings or maybe somethoing regarding de difference between url and path?

Comment: you're looking in public, right?

Comment: I knew I was retarded. Can you make your last comment an answer so I can accept it? Thanks a bunch. Don't hate me..

Comment: All set. No worries, it happens to us all. Glad I could help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you're looking in your `/public` directory instead of `/assets`.